# Sparse consolidation Algorithm in Congos TM1

Tags: algorithm, cognos, sparse-matrix, consolidation, cognos-tm1

How do the sparse consolidation algorithm helps to improve the Cognos TM1 performance?

Comment: what is sparse consolidation algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

I found a concise description here:

[Cognos TM1 Rules – how do they really work?](http://blogs.perficient.com/businessintelligence/2012/05/02/cognos-tm1-rules-how-do-they-really-work/)

> During consolidations, TM1 uses a sparse consolidation algorithm to
>   skip over cells that contain zero or are empty. This algorithm speeds
>   up consolidation calculations in cubes that are highly sparse.

Answer (score 0):

A comprehensive post on TM1 rules and consolidation:
[Skipcheck Feeders in TM1](http://tm1up.com/skipcheck-feeders-in-tm1.html)

It gives step by step process on how rules and consolidation works in TM1 and how skipcheck and feeders are used to improve the calculation speed.